# Quickbooks access to PayPal account data -- using Login with PayPal?

Tags: paypal, quickbooks

I want to create a system where I can access invoices data of paypal. Then I want to add those invoices form paypal to quickbooks. There are multiple paypal accounts. Its each data of paypal should be copied/synced to quickbook account.

If I look at the SaasAnat https://www.saasant.com/ which provides such way to login with paypal and access its data.

Is there any easy way to do it. Please let me know.

Comment: _"Is there any easy way to do it."_ - Why aren't you using https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/invoicing/v2/ directly?

Comment: That, or alternatively https://quickbooks.intuit.com/learn-support/en-us/help-article/bank-feeds/connect-paypal-faq/L1Np0fQ5E_US_en_US

Comment: @Dai Because it works only for one account. I need to connect multiple account at a time. How will I distinguish between them?

Comment: @TechLeadz use different API credentials for each PayPal account

Comment: @Dai We have resolved it, when a user login with quickbook it gives access token for each user. We have saved that access token against each user in our databse and now we can call all API end points using the access token for each account. Thanks.